# CONCAT de querys DELETE?

Tags: php

Tenho a seguinte **função**:

```
 public function excluir ($idPlano) {        

     $string1 = "DELETE FROM planos WHERE idPlano = ".$idPlano;
     $string2 = "DELETE FROM fotos WHERE idPlano = ".$idPlano;

     $this->conexao->query($string1);
     $this->conexao->query($string2);

 }
```

Gostaria de fazer algo como:

```
 public function excluir ($idPlano) {        

     $string = "DELETE FROM planos WHERE idPlano = ".$idPlano;
     $string .= "DELETE FROM fotos WHERE idPlano = ".$idPlano;

     return $this->conexao->query($string) ? 1 : 2;

 }
```

Fazer de 2 pesquisas apenas 1.

Tem como isso?

Meio que um **CONCAT**...

Comment: Se fizer `DELETE FROM plano, fotos ...` não funciona? Ou entao mude o final do sql para `idPlano = $idPlano;";` adicionando um `;` ao final da string

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
     public function excluir ($idPlano) {        

     $string = "DELETE planos, fotos FROM planos
                LEFT JOIN fotos  ON 
                    planos.idPlano = fotos.idPlano
                WHERE planos.idPlano = ".$idPlano;

     return $this->conexao->query($string);

 }
```

O `return` é só para saber se a **exclusão** foi ou não realizada.

No caso, no **MySQL** retorna 1 ou 2

Answer (score 0):

Se não me engano é assim:

```
$string1 = "
    DELETE planos.*,fotos.*
    FROM planos,fotos
    WHERE planos.idPlano = '$idPlano' AND planos.idPlano = fotos.idPlano 
";
$this->conexao->query($string1);
```

Se houvesse outra condição no `WHERE` para tabela fotos era só colocar um `nome_da_tabela.nome_do_campo='comparador'`

Comment: ou testar e depois falo.

Comment: Então, não funcionou! Alguma outra ideia? Ele não excluiu nem os itens  da tabela planos.